# Profile Post Code Search Finder Nearest Carrer

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web site that is Facebook for the old to find careers around the UK however the owner has asked for postcode partial search to be in place and that and a distance selection so they can search for careers in say 5 10 15 miles distances from the original postcode. I store postcode and long and latitude into the profile table.

userid int(11) Yes     NULL
profile_pic text    Yes     NULL
qualification   text    Yes     NULL
education   int(11) Yes     NULL
patient int(11) Yes     NULL
carer   int(11) Yes     NULL
telephone   varchar(50) Yes     NULL
mobile  varchar(50) Yes     NULL
gender  int(11) Yes     NULL
profile_areas   int(11) Yes     NULL
type    int(11) Yes     NULL
care_cats   int(11) No
lng varchar(20) No
lat varchar(20) No

My question is how would i create such a search the im reversing looking up long and lat via a third party search i need to give the distance avalble and show the profiles that match the distance

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

From: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html